# CKEditor 5 (audio) file uploader

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I found one related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56135981/generic-file-uploader-for-ckeditor-5-ckeditor-angular) but it is unanswered since three years.

My case should be pretty simple, I want to be able to upload audio files to our server and then embed them via simple audio html tag.

The custom image uploader is working and the code on the server could handle audio files as well.

Do I really have to write a custom plugin for this? Seems pretty overkill, especially as the image upload is already implemented and working flawlessly...